# Online registration - fill-in boxes both above and below text

Tags: wordpress, online-registration

Is there any way on the online registration page for an event to include the fill-in boxes for name, email etc. both above and below several paragraphs of text?  Right now it is only appearing below the introductory text.

The idea is to handle two scenarios: 1) Someone comes to the page ready to register and can do so right away without having to scroll down through the introductory text, 2) Someone comes to the site, scrolls through the introductory text and can register without having to go back up to the top to register.

So, two identical sets of fill-in boxes, one set before the introductory text and one after.

WordPress 4.7.4 CiviCRM 4.7.17

Comment: do you mean 'both above and below' or 'either above or below'? If you mean 'both' then I can't understand why you would want the Name field to be in both positions on the one form so perhaps you could flesh this out

Comment: I hope the added material makes the intention clearer.

Comment: Assuming this doesn't break some laws of code you will have to customise the template that is used. if having two blocks is problematic why not put a 'back to top/form' at the bottom of the text?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to accomplish this depending on your needs.

If you are using a WP shortcode on a page you can have text above and below the registration block. This option allows specific intro text or text after registration form but does not insert text in specific areas of the form.

If you use multiple profiles on the page You can use the pre & post form help entries in the profile settings to add specific text.

Finally in the individual fields there is also the options to add pre & post help. In these fields you can use html tags to format text the way you wish.

Some custom CSS may be necessary to get things the way you like. Hope these options help out.

Comment: Hopefully, I have made it clear now with added material that I want the registration block above and below the text, not text above and below the registration block.